# C++ inline function inside a static class or namespace

Tags: c++

I have a very small function that could be a macro, but anyway, I thought inline function would do exactly the same.

But nah, when I mark a function in a namespace as `inline` it is not visible by any other file that includes my module.

I tried it both with a static class and a namespace. No error when the function is declared or implemented, error in each reference, exactly as if the function was static.

Is there a way to have an inline function available for other files that include the file where my function is declared?

Let's say I have a module that handles some hardware stuff, and one of the functions is something like this:

```cpp
bool getState(HWFlag flag)
{
    return (State & flag) > 0
}
```

I know, it can be written as macro, but logically the function is a part of a bigger module. I would certainly used a macro in C, but it's C++ so I thought there might be a better way. But well, I obviously don't understand how it works.

BTW, shouldn't the compiler just inline it anyway so I shouldn't even care?

BTW2: Is making the module that mainly talks with C code a class with only static method a bad idea or does it have any use? That's how I made it initially but later decided to just make it a namespace to simplify the syntax a little. But in any case, if I use the `inline` keyword the function becomes private.

Comment: Put the function into a header file, with `inline` keyword. To be able to inline, the compiler needs to see the function's implementation at the point where it's called.

Comment: If you wanted a macro to be used in multiple files you would put it in a header file. It's the same with an inline function. But I'm finding your description a little hard to follow, if the function already is in a header file then we need precise detail, actual code, not descriptions of code, to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Side note: `inline` is just a suggestion to the compiler, one that the compiler will effectively ignore. When the compiler optimizes it'll decide whether to inline or not, and for something small like `getState`, it most likely will, `inline` specified or not. What `inline` really does these days is allow you to define a function in a header without multiple definitions by every file that includes the header.

Comment: "_But nah, when I mark a function in a namespace as inline it is not visible by any other file that includes my module._": Marking the function `inline` (and defining it in the header, inside the namespace if you want) is correct and should work. Please provide a [mre] if it doesn't. You must then have some more subtle mistake here or I don't understand what you mean. Also note that since C++20 the term "_module_" has a very specific meaning and I don't have the feeling that you really mean that here. I think you mean something informal instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `inline` function should be defined identically in every translation unit that uses it.  So you should define your inline function exactly as you would a macro--in a header file that gets included by all of the files that need it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've understood correctly - "defined" means something completely different than "declared" right? So in my header I shouldn't have just function declaration, but the function itself? I've just tested it and it obviously works. My mistake was to have a separate declaration in the header file. When I put the function body in the header it works as expected.

Comment: Yes, a function definition includes the function body.  Unlike a non-inline function, where you only need the declaration, for an inline function you need the actual definition.